# jQuery For Loop calculation on array

Tags: jquery

I need to do some calculation for a mileage price in jQuery.

Say for example distance = 10

On a tariff such as:

```
----------------------------
| Mileage | Rate           |
----------------------------
|    1    | 1.5            |
----------------------------
|    5    | 3              | 
----------------------------
|   999   | 1.2            | 
----------------------------
```

Which means it would be £1.50 for the first mile, £3.00 for the 2nd to 5th and then £1.20 for every additional mile.

This would make the 10 mile journey = £19.50

I don't really know where to start so any help would be much appreciated.

All I can think of is:-

```
var distance = 10

// create a key value pair (although this isn't correct)
var tariff = {mileage: 1, rate: 1.5, mileage: 5, rate: 3, mileage: 999, rate: 1.2};
```

and then looping the tariff:-

```
for (var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
    //multiply mileage by rate
}

//get sum of values from loop
```

Comment: Looks like you have the code concepts figured out essentially and just need to sit down with a pencil and paper and work out the math formula. Not really clear what your specific problem is

Comment: try this : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/fxvfpoaw/

Comment: Thanks @DinoMyte - only thing is I would need to add probably more steps, i.e. for up to 10 miles, up to 20, up to 30 and so on. Then do the same for different vehicle types so this might get a bit complicated.

Comment: Take a moment and think about it. Then update your question with the code you think should be good enought and let people review your code instead. This way you would probably get a better answer as we don't know the full scope of what you'r after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option.

change your tariff object to an array and do a reverse `for` loop, using `i` as the current mile.

```js
var distance = 10; cost = 0;

var tariff = [{ mileage: 1, rate: 1.5 },{ mileage: 5, rate: 3 },{ mileage: 999, rate: 1.2 }];

for (var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
  var milePrice = 0;
  for (var j = tariff.length; j--;) {
    if (i < tariff[j].mileage)
      milePrice = tariff[j].rate;
  }
  cost += milePrice;
}

document.write(cost.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this quick example might be what your looking for, or at least a good place to start.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {           
   var distance = $(this).val();
    var cost = 0;
    var tariff = [{mileage: 1, rate: 1.5}, {mileage: 5, rate: 3}, {mileage: 999, rate: 1.2}];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
     //multiply mileage by rate
      if(i < tariff[0].mileage) {
       cost += tariff[0].rate;
      } else if(i < tariff[1].mileage) {
       cost += tariff[1].rate;
      } else if(i < tariff[2].mileage) {
       cost += tariff[2].rate;
      }
    }
    
    $('#cost').html(cost.toFixed(2));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>Mileage</label>
  <input type='number' value='0'/>
</form>
<p>Cost: <span id='cost'></span></p>
```